# detect related model or create in django

Tags: django

I have two models

```
# models.py 
class Expert(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)

class Meeting(models.Model):
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    timezone = TimeZoneField(default="America/New_York")
```

What's the best way to write a view that will create a Meeting with an Existing Expert in the database OR create a new Expert and associate it with the new Meeting?

my forms

```
# forms.py

class ExpertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Name"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Expert
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "company",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "company": autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
                url="company_private",
                attrs={
                    "data-placeholder": "Company",
                    "data-delay": "250",
                    "data-tags": "true",
                },
            )
        }

class MeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = [
            "start",
            "timezone",
            "expert",
        ]


class MeetingDateAMPMForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Meeting Form with support for calendar and am/pm format."""

    date_format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
    # django_date_format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
    start = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=[date_format], widget=DateTimePickerInput(format=date_format),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = [
            "start",
            "timezone",
            "expert",
        ]

    def clean_expert(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["expert"]
        if not data:
            raise ValidationError("An expert is required to create a meeting.")
        return data
```

my view thusfar

```
# views.py
def meeting_expert_create(request):
    logger.info("meeting_expert_create: running")
    est_offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
    if request.method == "POST":
        meeting_form = MeetingDateAMPMForm(request.POST)
        expert_form = ExpertForm(request.POST)
        params = request.POST.copy()

        if request.POST["company"]:
            expert_form.is_valid()
            expert = expert_form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Expert created.")
        else:
            expert = request.POST.get("expert")
        meeting_form = MeetingDateAMPMForm(params)

        if meeting_form.is_valid():
            logger.info(
                f"meeting_expert_create: meeting form valid meeting {meeting_form.cleaned_data}"
            )
            logger.info(f"meeting_expert_create: expert {expert}")
            meeting = meeting_form.save(commit=False)
            meeting.analyst = request.user
            meeting.start += est_offset
            meeting.expert = expert
            meeting.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Meeting created.")
            on_commit(lambda: email_approvers.delay(meeting.id))
            logger.info(f"meeting_expert_create: complete.")
        else:
            errors = str(meeting_form.errors) + str(expert_form.errors)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, errors)
            logger.info(f"meeting_expert_create: complete.")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))
```

I need to be able to create a Meeting. The Meeting's Expert may already exist or we receive the info necessary to build the Expert. In both cases the Meeting should have a foreign key to an Expert. A Meeting should not be created without an Expert.

Comment: i think you need inlineformset_factory. take a look at https://gist.github.com/mh-firouzjaah/dc707b802617e517326582b6b9ffc363

Comment: I don't really understand formsets. I think the solution is to do a conditional on the POST data and construct the forms appropriately.